# ggplot2: adding density lines on scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to add density plot on scatter plot using ggplot library. In the following example, I want to have two density plots separated by different color each representing the data based on a condition.  I get an error saying:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Here is the example:

```
library(ggplot2)
cylcon <- ifelse(mpg$cyl>4,1,0)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x =displ, y = hwy)) +
 geom_point(aes(size = cyl, col=cyl)) +
 geom_density2d(mpg,  aes(displ,hwy, fill =factor(cylcon), alpha=1/2))
```

Comment: `data` isn't the first argument in geom layers, only in `ggplot`.  So you need to use the argument name like `data = mpg` in `geom_density2d`.  As you defined the dataset globally in `ggplot` you can also simply take the call to the dataset out of `geom_density2d` all together.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Do you know how I can add the color argument to that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want your graph to look like.  Have you tried `stat_density2d` with `geom = "polygon"`?  I'd recommending asking a new question.